How to configure self-referencing foreign key relationship in sqlalchemy ORM?
I have a node model.
A node can have many children and a parent
i need a way to model this relation
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    node_id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    parrent_id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("node.node_id"))

    parrent_node : Mapped[Optional["Node"]] = relationship(back_populates="child_nodes")
    child_nodes : Mapped[Optional[List["Node"]]] = relationship(back_populates="parrent_node")


how to configure the back_populates params correctly when both sides of the relationship are on the same class?

Self-referential relationship configuration is documented in Adjacency List Relationships.
For the code in the question, what is needed is to set the remote_side attribute on the parent relationship.
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't79223609'

    node_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    label: Mapped[str]
    parent_id: Mapped[int | None] = mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('t79223609.node_id'))

    parent_node: Mapped['Node | None'] = orm.relationship(
        back_populates='child_nodes', remote_side=[node_id]
    )
    child_nodes: Mapped[list['Node']] = orm.relationship(back_populates='parent_node')


